# How to Rank and find latest record

Tags: sql

i have this dataset
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6uT9.png)

```
CREATE TABLE  test (
    p_name      VARCHAR(40) ,
    p_date      date NOT NULL,
    p_time      time(0),
    p_areaname  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    p_direction DECIMAL(10,2) 
)

select * from test

truncate table test 

insert into test values
('adam', '05/10/2022', '9:00', 'it building', 1),
('adam', '05/10/2022', '9:10','global', 0),
('adam', '05/10/2022', '10:00','it building', 1),
('adam', '05/10/2022', '10:10','global', 0),
('adam', '05/10/2022', '11:00','it building', 1),
('adam', '05/10/2022', '11:10','global', 0),
('adam', '05/10/2022', '11:15','global', 0)
;
```

I want to identify latest record from each p_areaname and p_direction,

pleaes help,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcF7W.png)

Comment: How do you determine what the  "latest record" is, exactly?

Comment: Also, you _really should_ mark your columns as `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   p_name 
        ,p_date 
        ,p_time 
        ,p_areaname 
        ,p_direction
from    (
        select  *
                ,rank() over(partition by p_areaname, p_direction order by p_date desc, p_time desc) as rnk
        from    test
        ) t
where   rnk = 1
```

| p_name | p_date | p_time | p_areaname | p_direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| adam | 2022-10-05 | 11:15:00 | global | 0.00 |
| adam | 2022-10-05 | 11:00:00 | it building | 1.00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9zDVoaYM)